# DataTables, print with counter column

Tags: printing, datatables

I have a table with counter column, but when I print it counter column are empty. And there is a 'id' column. which is hidden in table view.

How can I print with counter column?!

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": 'lBfrtip',
        "buttons": [ 'print'],
        "ajax": "data/mine.txt",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "" },
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" },
            { "data": "functions" }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<qwerty_1>Bla bla!</qwerty_1>"
        } ],
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]

    } );


    table.column(1).visible(false);

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'qwerty_1', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        alert(data['id']);
    } );

    table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();

} );
```

Comment: Please post some of your code, otherwise we can only guess

Comment: Im sorry... Already, done it.

Comment: @S.DeaV It's always a good idea when you accept an answer to upvote it too.

Comment: @Moses Machua. I'm sorry. I didn't realize and didn't know how to do it...

Comment: I am having issue while printing can you help me out please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776387/formatting-the-output-of-datatable-when-there-are-filters-around-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for a [counter column](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html) which you are using from datatables documentation here does not actually add the value of the column to the table within datatables' memory, but rather just sets the html in the DOM. This is why it is showing up blank when you print the table. However, you can extend the "print" functionality to run a custom script on your print page to create the result you want.

Try changing the "buttons" declaration to something like this:

```
"buttons": [{
    extend: 'print',
    customize: function(win) {
        $(win.document.body).find( 'tr' ).each( function(index) {
             $(this).find('td:first').html(index);
        });
    }
 }],
```

If you want to play with it, I figured this out with a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xfa0x93/)

Comment: is there a way to capture the counter values with default settings and pass it to a server variable with out clicking any button?

Comment: I am having issue while printing can you help me out please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776387/formatting-the-output-of-datatable-when-there-are-filters-around-it

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Adam's answer for printing, here's how you add line counter to Excel or CSV export.

```
buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Export To Excel',
            exportOptions: {
                format: {
                    body: function (data, rowindex, colindex, node) {
                        // add row count to first column
                        return colindex === 0? rowindex + 1: data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

CSV works the same.

Comment: I am having issue while printing can you help me out please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776387/formatting-the-output-of-datatable-when-there-are-filters-around-it